# LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH inner join with case in SQL DBMS

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT
    A.WORKNR AS "WORK-nr", 
    UCASE(A.NAME) AS "NAME" ,
    UCASE(A.ADRESS) AS "adress",
    A.ZIPNR,
    UCASE(A.ZIPADR) AS "zipadress", 
    A.NNR, 
    CASE
        WHEN AO.ORG_REF IS NULL THEN 'OK'
        ELSE 'NO ' 
    END AS RESULT OF ORG ,
    CASE
        WHEN B.B = 1 THEN 'OK' 
        ELSE 'COME WITH ANOTHER NNR' 
    END AS COMPARE_RESULT 
FROM
    WORK.WORK_ADRESS A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         POSTNR, UCASE(STREET) AS STREET, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT NNR) AS B
     FROM
         WORK.WORK_ADRESS 
     GROUP BY
         ZIPNR, UCASE(STREET)) B ON B.STREET = UCASE(A.STREET) 
                                 AND B.ZIPNR = ZIPNR
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM WORK.ORGANISATION2) AO ON AO.WORK_REF = A.WORK_REF 
                                 AND AO.TILL >= CURRENT DATE
```

what I want is to add a `JOIN` to a third table `ORG3` that contains the name for org genom

```
SELECT WORK.ORGANISATION2 
INNER JOIN STYR.ORG2 ORG3 ON AO.ORG_REF3 = ORG3.ORG_REF
```

and get the column `OR3.NAME` as a separate column.

Can anyone help me? I am thankful